# Use selector to call function with parameters

Tags: swift, timer

My Swift code looks like this:

```
class SystemClass {
    public init() {}
    func setXYZ(xyz: Float32) {
        // do something
    }
}

let callME: class = class()
class class {
  public init() {}
  func functionXYZ() {  
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(SystemClass().setXYZ(xyz: 1.0)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true) // error code
  }
}

callME.functionXYZ()
```

I'd like to call the '`functionXYZ`' and this is already working fine but calling the `setXYZ` function leads to errors because the selector failed.

How to edit the selector:

```
#selector(SystemClass().setXYZ(xyz: 1.0))
```

to call the `setXYZ` function with the given parameter?

Comment: You can't pass param this way, the selector awaits for the signature, not with params. You could use the `userInfo` instead.

Comment: Please don't rollback useful edits. Do not use irrelevant tags. Do not put tags and needless commentary in your title. I also fixed other formatting as well. No need to undo all of those useful and appropriate changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Updating to include pre-iOS 10.0 solution

In this case it'd be better to use the `scheduledTimer` function that takes a block, as this will allow you to pass arguments to your function:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    SystemClass().setXYZ(xyz: 1.0)
}
```

**For pre-iOS 10.0:**

You can also pass userInfo in, including this default value, and then access that info from your inside your selector, like this:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(SystemClass().setXYZ(_:)), userInfo: 1.0, repeats: true)
```

To do this you'd also have to modify your `setXYZ` function signature to look like this:

```
@objc func setXYZ(_ sender: Timer) {
    if let xyz = sender.userInfo as? Float {
        print(xyz)
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Mhm, looks fine but I get this error `scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:repeats:block:)' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer`

Comment: OK, check the edit for older iOS targets.

Comment: The target can't be `self` since the selector is not in the same class.